# C++ self registering class member

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to achieve the following: A client class `foo` either inherits from a class named `properties` or uses it as a class member. The client class `foo` may also have zero or more members of type `property`. Each `property` member should self-register itself with the `properties` instance of the client class:

```
struct foo :
    properties
{
    property<int> x;
    property<int> y;
};
```

The idea is to allow the client class to specify any number of properties which are automatically "collected" for further processing such as serialization so that the author of the client class does not need to manually enumerate/iterate each property.

What techniques can I use to achieve this? I know about patterns for self-registering classes that register themselves at a static factory but how would one achieve self-registration at a specific instance within the same client class automatically? Is this even possible? Given that [`Q_PROPERTY`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) does something similar there should be a way of doing this?

Anything up to C++20 (at least what's currently available in GCC 10.2) is fine.

This question is a more specific question towards a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858079/c-properties-library-design) of mine.

Comment: using something like `map<string, any>`?

Comment: How would the `property` members auto-register themselves at the `properties` instance of the class they are contained within?

Comment: Sounds like key-value pairs of strings.  `map<string, string>`.

Comment: Q_PROPERTY uses code generation to achieve this. Check the generated `moc_*.cpp` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it fully automatically but you can get somewhere near:

```
#include <map>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct property {};

struct properties
{
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<std::shared_ptr<property<int>>>> properties;

    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<property<T>> make_prop(const std::string& name)
    {
        auto prop = std::make_shared<property<T>>();
        properties[name] = prop;
        return prop;
    }
};

struct foo :
    properties
{
    std::shared_ptr<property<int>> x = make_prop<int>("x");
    std::shared_ptr<property<int>> y = make_prop<int>("y");
};

int main () {
    foo f;
}
```

depending on your requirements you might want `std::any` rather than `std::variant`.

You could add a macro for declaring properties:

```
#define MAKE_PROP(name, type) \
  std::shared_ptr<property<type>> name = make_prop<type>(#name);

struct bar :
    properties
{
    MAKE_PROP(x, int);
    MAKE_PROP(y, int);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for illustrating a possible solution! The map value type of `std::variant<property<int>>` would be a problem tho as other properties would wrap other types. I guess I'll have to combine it with runtime polymorphism as proposed by @ypnos or is there a way of achieving something similar to `std::map<std::string, std::variant<property<T>>>` ?

Comment: Well of course you can add other types to the variant, a variant with a single type is pretty pointless, if there isn't a fixed set of types you can use `std::any` instead

Comment: When using this approach, the property stored in the `properties` map is a different copy of what the client class using `MAKE_PROP()` gets, right? Therefore, when iterating over all properties in the map (eg. to serialize them) I do not get the correct values as they are different copies. I would need to store pointers to the properties created by `MAKE_PROP()` in the map instead instead. However, I don't see a way of doing this in `properties::make_prop()` as the function has no way of knowing the address at which the copy of the return value will be stored.

Comment: Nothing in your question stated that `property` wasn't copyable (you didn't provide a [mre]) if it isn't then probably the easiest solution is to use `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 5):

A simple design could be:

- Properties derive from a common base class and are themselves templated wrappers for their type (e.g. int, string, ..)
- Property-holders have a map of properties, e.g. `std::map<std::string, Property*> properties;`
- Constructors of properties take pointer to holder as argument, self-register with holder

An example from Herbstluftwm (C++11):

1. [Object class](https://github.com/herbstluftwm/herbstluftwm/blob/master/src/object.h)
2. [Attribute class](https://github.com/herbstluftwm/herbstluftwm/blob/master/src/attribute_.h)
3. [Example object with attributes: Tag](https://github.com/herbstluftwm/herbstluftwm/blob/master/src/tag.h) ([initialization in cpp](https://github.com/herbstluftwm/herbstluftwm/blob/master/src/tag.cpp#L31))

Comment: Thank you for proposing this solution. That's definitely what I want to achieve.
Is there a way to automatically register the property (`Attribute` in herbstluftwm) when it gets declared so the user of the property system does not have to both declare it as a member and also manually initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. That's why it is the way it is in Herbstluftwm. Might be able to  do it with macros (see https://github.com/woboq/verdigris which is Qt w/o MOC, so pure C++14), if you want to go that route. However note that the Qt properties are not as 'intelligent'; you wouldn't get signals/events when a variable is changed.